# Editar valores de un formulario que se encuentra dentro de un script

Tags: javascript, html, script

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente codigo. que hace parte de un html el cual genera un botón de pago, pero los valores que están dentro del script no encuentro como volverlos input para editarlos y hacerlos variables según el pago, como puedo editarlos? como se puede convertir en un form normal con submit? o como puedo editarlos para que no sean valores fijos? agracederé su ayuda.

```
     <script
        src="https://checkout.epayco.co/checkout.js"
        class="epayco-button"
        data-epayco-key="01ea48a6dc845rr4179399b747777cef5"  
        data-epayco-invoice= "rt0uuyyy31"
        data-epayco-amount= "78000"
        data-epayco-name="Vestido Mujer Primavera"
        data-epayco-description="Vestido Mujer Primavera"
        data-epayco-currency="cop"
        data-epayco-country="co"
        data-epayco-test= "true"
        data-epayco-external="true"
        data-epayco-response="https://secure.epayco.co/validation/v1/reference/"
        data-epayco-email-billing="ejemplo@dominio.com"
        data-epayco-name-billing="Andres Perez"
        data-epayco-address-billing="Carrera 19 numero 14 91"
        data-epayco-type-doc-billing="CC"
        data-epayco-mobilephone-billing="3051230000"
        data-epayco-number-doc-billing="1073000000"
        data-epayco-confirmation="https://google.com">
             
    </script>
```

Comment: Quieres hacer un input en HTML, y poder manejar el valor ingresado en el input en Javascript?

Comment: Hola si asi es, como lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, la acabo de postear.

Comment: Me sale error al poner una variable con guiones (-) no me acepta la variable que necesito data-epayco-address-billling.

Comment: Recuerda que debes de poner el Id entre comillas (""). Ejemplo `var div = document.getElementById("div");`